# Some of the gravatars in the Newsletter don't belong to the user

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-picture, gravatar, newsletter

Thanks for the weekly Meta Newsletter.

There seems to be something off with the gravatars of some users:

> [image: newsletter with wrong avatars]

Shog9's avatar is

> [image: Shog9]

If I disassemble the link in the newsletter I find this gravatar url:

> `https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/faf0644479544af142cbd0dfeeb46264?s=18&d=identicon&r=PG`

and that doesn't match the with the profileimageurl of Shog9. I can't really determine if it belongs to anyone else.

The gravatar of Ian Ringrose is also wrong.

Strangely enough the other profile images seem okay, although in an earlier report [Last entry in newsletter has messed-up user links, gravatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306533/158100) there are also gravatars wrong.

I checked my email history and in December 2017 this didn't seem to occur for the newsletters received back then. Can this be investigated to confirm if this is yet another quirk of Gravatar or maybe a regression due to the newsletter overhaul that took place in January?

Comment: I think it's the same issue as I was getting [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/283643/323179), but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: @Laurel well, I recalled that bug, but I assume that in all the examples you show the gravatar hash is stable. That is not the case, I think, here. But it is worth to keep your post in mind as it might be related.

Answer (score 6):

Well this is entirely my fault - I mixed up two `string` parameters when calling `User.GetProfileImageUrl` and the underlying code generated an invalid hash for users using Gravatar for their profile image.

I probably should have picked this up earlier but all my test accounts used images from Google profiles rather than Gravatar.

A fix is on its way to prod and will take effect for the next batch of newsletters sent later today.