# Please condense the markup for Stack Exchange newsletters

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

(This was already mentioned in [Last entry in newsletter has messed-up user links, gravatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306533/last-entry-in-newsletter-has-messed-up-user-links-gravatars) but not as an actionable [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).)

Gmail (which many people are surely using using to receive newsletters) imposes a limit on the size of HTML messages it will display:

[image]

So that I can conveniently read the entire newsletter rather than only part of it, I would like to request that some attention be given to reducing the size of the HTML which is used in the newsletter.

From what I can see, there is plenty of room for optimization; an absurd number of characters are used for click-tracking URLs, and also a substantial amount of indentation. Look at this *single question!* (Pardon the leftover MIME encoding `=3D`s.)

```
<tr>
    <td width=3D"580" valign=3D"top" style=3D"padding-top: 0; background-co=
lor: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;">
        <h3 style=3D"margin: 10px 0;">
            <a href=3D"http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/click?upn=3Dp=
DzA4vSaPmKy14MynsLvnRQTBtamz6vS9tZen0pRKrmwKC2oZBYrtK5mbRruBkjEwh8JQZ07PySK=
HqnVmguzLYNHq5o4ozV4MkO85TMWPvc-3D_pSGix6lcXMpI2ZlzD19wA3oOB7aPlHNwDWh-2BLK=
f8z2vPGH-2BBxqSsaz2YL42V7koOY4iZg1ru4GjpuV0Xny3pWdCCIInyP8UWMGJqPQsGwUkFh-2=
FBeSGfNi7v70w2eOPYNAtrshI1eu6eaJJPXhEG-2BRpZjijUwt6YGFW42Nx7GVt8fKVPnWSB-2F=
51ESovNL9iKyokqAQgod5tIOwZlhhhAGNgPhzsXXN-2BsA1Ja-2FZDggJcBDSquEy7K0-2Fallm=
M64la7ANOYSphhpilw2KFQzY2PTseZXXhq1-2FM3lNhrvzLa8JxwCm0-2BBSnsvT4wDMRxwX18g=
fOaLlfvUTeJodwK-2BA-2FbH-2Fu5QijqKuA-2FMIcBjfGT1J9JCaFqlN2YXMHk-2Fglz0qRBIo=
qgFkt3m4lw8rHcwFV8vaMzmzijZc1E1gD9mSl89XRHGaQee5h3iOFNkZli2tNWyICoP-2Bc75OX=
hOrFzseb-2BqzIRzYqx4cQnNB27GftWPZAqtCa90ggAphWNvSy4TEV3V" target=3D"_blank"=
 style=3D"color: #2DB9C5!important; font-size: 17px!important; text-decorat=
ion: none!important; font-weight: normal!important;">Estimation of step amp=
litude using the CUSUM algorithm</a>
        </h3>
        <p style=3D"margin: 1em 0;font-size: 14px; color: #444;">I used the=
 CUSUM algorithm to detect steps in data. Basically the data looks like thi=
s, the data has a constant amplitude and then there is a rapid variation or=
 a step. For example, the signal has a  ... </p>
       =20
        <table width=3D"580" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"=
0">
            <tr>
                <td align=3D"left" valign=3D"top">
=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<a href=3D"http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/clic=
k?upn=3DpDzA4vSaPmKy14MynsLvnRQTBtamz6vS9tZen0pRKrmwKC2oZBYrtK5mbRruBkjEMTt=
X3j1efBZGKcfDP-2BqCYYiGTZ2p-2BPX-2FvmkLVo-2FWhlPTfva5h6ysGuL7manhppei_pSGix=
6lcXMpI2ZlzD19wA3oOB7aPlHNwDWh-2BLKf8z2vPGH-2BBxqSsaz2YL42V7koOY4iZg1ru4Gjp=
uV0Xny3pWdCCIInyP8UWMGJqPQsGwUkFh-2FBeSGfNi7v70w2eOPYNAtrshI1eu6eaJJPXhEG-2=
BRpZjijUwt6YGFW42Nx7GVt8fKVPnWSB-2F51ESovNL9iKyokqAQgod5tIOwZlhhhAGNgPhzsXX=
N-2BsA1Ja-2FZDggJcBDSquEy7K0-2FallmM64la7ANOYSphhpilw2KFQzY2PTseZXXhq1-2FM3=
lNhrvzLa8Jxxg3mJRIoRZBvVML1O3VMZ6HOMTMP-2BYNEWOL0G1is3IRJm5PqO6QC-2BN2-2B3A=
CjoyJGK1XyqDt3ezty0YEW4OTvOYy1C1Rg3rtAViJAIAbn-2BoQgE4Owtc5W9-2FPH0KN-2FwEH=
j-2BY8eB0e33M5Htac1GjbWilG3fm-2FG5afcFU8WBytLE-2BQRdFf3OZl015476F2MLUMq-2F3=
ONTtDEsIZWiOFlRrUwkt" target=3D"_blank" style=3D"display: inline-block; whi=
te-space: nowrap; overflow: visible;color: #626262; background-color: #efee=
ee; border-color: transparent; padding: 0.4em 0.7em; margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;=
 font-size: 11px; line-height: 1; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: non=
e; text-align: center;">estimation</a>
=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<a href=3D"http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/clic=
k?upn=3DpDzA4vSaPmKy14MynsLvnRQTBtamz6vS9tZen0pRKrmwKC2oZBYrtK5mbRruBkjEMTt=
X3j1efBZGKcfDP-2BqCYbLy4XsBPwrjqJqLRXwU4kI-3D_pSGix6lcXMpI2ZlzD19wA3oOB7aPl=
HNwDWh-2BLKf8z2vPGH-2BBxqSsaz2YL42V7koOY4iZg1ru4GjpuV0Xny3pWdCCIInyP8UWMGJq=
PQsGwUkFh-2FBeSGfNi7v70w2eOPYNAtrshI1eu6eaJJPXhEG-2BRpZjijUwt6YGFW42Nx7GVt8=
fKVPnWSB-2F51ESovNL9iKyokqAQgod5tIOwZlhhhAGNgPhzsXXN-2BsA1Ja-2FZDggJcBDSquE=
y7K0-2FallmM64la7ANOYSphhpilw2KFQzY2PTseZXXhq1-2FM3lNhrvzLa8JxzCdOKACirRoP4=
rZGXSsLFSox-2Fj2Z5UF1wru3LcNarQOvCsy3F7y2ItoHGwAX3j4As8ry-2B6mq7rZUarnrqWXF=
AZ9KDIGuRpEuNbSVoCNdgdR4hfjYdjYV1dfBkvTh2LlKEK9XUhu6EuxhvtSwMqimnLBqSyOenGi=
Gxt9l1mNfGS31kcqzzI9GyMv-2BR-2BR3bxgR4I-2BTmEbkwFuNSEIZLODoxN" target=3D"_b=
lank" style=3D"display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: visibl=
e;color: #626262; background-color: #efeeee; border-color: transparent; pad=
ding: 0.4em 0.7em; margin: 2px 2px 2px 0; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1; =
white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;">amplitude<=
/a>
=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<a href=3D"http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/clic=
k?upn=3DpDzA4vSaPmKy14MynsLvnRQTBtamz6vS9tZen0pRKrmwKC2oZBYrtK5mbRruBkjEMTt=
X3j1efBZGKcfDP-2BqCYURwN2gUfWh8LfiopoBHtdw-3D_pSGix6lcXMpI2ZlzD19wA3oOB7aPl=
HNwDWh-2BLKf8z2vPGH-2BBxqSsaz2YL42V7koOY4iZg1ru4GjpuV0Xny3pWdCCIInyP8UWMGJq=
PQsGwUkFh-2FBeSGfNi7v70w2eOPYNAtrshI1eu6eaJJPXhEG-2BRpZjijUwt6YGFW42Nx7GVt8=
fKVPnWSB-2F51ESovNL9iKyokqAQgod5tIOwZlhhhAGNgPhzsXXN-2BsA1Ja-2FZDggJcBDSquE=
y7K0-2FallmM64la7ANOYSphhpilw2KFQzY2PTseZXXhq1-2FM3lNhrvzLa8JxxlbSipKKARsBm=
8AyiFfyVbTEsXOeu1RKrFP71azsAhUVpK-2B9EvAX9d2e9Yww3u5K96ANNlh0KU-2F96P7eCViB=
C3HjoG2GecVq2Ox8vIQvXq8n37DwvXXOSaLYJOo7OLf9hHnfHMaWbzdylpKnMKrpW-2FBjh1thO=
4N7vXPr6VFFDL6H-2FmsWNJq0fZKnMcOOnpW8zY7Cb6P6t-2FJrrwUdB7h0-2Fp" target=3D"=
_blank" style=3D"display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap; overflow: visi=
ble;color: #626262; background-color: #efeeee; border-color: transparent; p=
adding: 0.4em 0.7em; margin: 2px 2px 2px 0; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1=
; white-space: nowrap; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;">cusum</a=
>
                </td>
                <td style=3D"padding-top: 0; color: #888; font-size: 11px;"=
 width=3D"20">&nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=3D"top" width=3D"225">
                    <table width=3D"225" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0=
" border=3D"0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style=3D"padding-top: 0;">
                    <img src=3D"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b4a5962dece=
9c508b16757248b107953?s=3D18&amp;d=3Didenticon&amp;r=3DPG" align=3D"right" =
width=3D"18" height=3D"18" />
            </td>
            <td style=3D"padding-top: 0; color: #888; font-size: 11px;">
                    asked by
                    <a href=3D"http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/click=
?upn=3DpDzA4vSaPmKy14MynsLvnRQTBtamz6vS9tZen0pRKrmwKC2oZBYrtK5mbRruBkjEOt60=
O13BhXoh6hHWdAm5FuuQ49aIemMXCkNNJdfv4SM-3D_pSGix6lcXMpI2ZlzD19wA3oOB7aPlHNw=
DWh-2BLKf8z2vPGH-2BBxqSsaz2YL42V7koOY4iZg1ru4GjpuV0Xny3pWdCCIInyP8UWMGJqPQs=
GwUkFh-2FBeSGfNi7v70w2eOPYNAtrshI1eu6eaJJPXhEG-2BRpZjijUwt6YGFW42Nx7GVt8fKV=
PnWSB-2F51ESovNL9iKyokqAQgod5tIOwZlhhhAGNgPhzsXXN-2BsA1Ja-2FZDggJcBDSquEy7K=
0-2FallmM64la7ANOYSphhpilw2KFQzY2PTseZXXhq1-2FM3lNhrvzLa8JxxtATRkE9-2BFSsUk=
wBKYwbqLb7-2BNSzBFPDlsnDaIalohrRgy49Bw8qr8hbyO0O3jCBqngjhgGJAud0SDKUeFFrHSB=
qL9yrVpmxG9B7Wi0byXnccnBqpAUKEiN7RKgrQg3KWLZCAvrPGYqqZqDOIS1SuwfI-2BfgXExNm=
-2BUINvQ0B-2F5q3pAP1i8pXJcOz7fgqtbodYLIU7ZpkZ5Ue-2FkzZl8949h" target=3D"_bl=
ank" style=3D"color: #2DB9C5; text-decoration: none!important;">Ben</a>
3 votes            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
                           =20

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style=3D"padding-top: 0;">
                    <img src=3D"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5b3b07e3c59=
aaf39ae54ccdea43670e5?s=3D18&amp;d=3Didenticon&amp;r=3DPG" align=3D"right" =
width=3D"18" height=3D"18" />
            </td>
            <td style=3D"padding-top: 0; color: #888; font-size: 11px;">
                    answered by
                    <a href=3D"http://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/wf/click=
?upn=3DpDzA4vSaPmKy14MynsLvnRQTBtamz6vS9tZen0pRKrmwKC2oZBYrtK5mbRruBkjEOt60=
O13BhXoh6hHWdAm5FlI4fPmGXEYupZPMZTeHxSU-3D_pSGix6lcXMpI2ZlzD19wA3oOB7aPlHNw=
DWh-2BLKf8z2vPGH-2BBxqSsaz2YL42V7koOY4iZg1ru4GjpuV0Xny3pWdCCIInyP8UWMGJqPQs=
GwUkFh-2FBeSGfNi7v70w2eOPYNAtrshI1eu6eaJJPXhEG-2BRpZjijUwt6YGFW42Nx7GVt8fKV=
PnWSB-2F51ESovNL9iKyokqAQgod5tIOwZlhhhAGNgPhzsXXN-2BsA1Ja-2FZDggJcBDSquEy7K=
0-2FallmM64la7ANOYSphhpilw2KFQzY2PTseZXXhq1-2FM3lNhrvzLa8Jxyx67HF2d-2FD5UXw=
Mt0kLYW0LERbmvCGAjI25rRSCV8vtA-2BEZdF7OqB3cFd39hoR-2FeaOW2iCBtGIZXXHPh-2F-2=
BgQuWJxF8GW-2BVlJtp7CdftAPFeJuHNS2iRS3Q-2FBCkhpO5YXDH9XZsxiSEMPQqL4ZNkpd8Eg=
fXZVcYLSzMGsNob6DuCkl9-2FGpASl9ltaXBnhqmKoaTKhXddtlHl2-2BIjXhLiPrE" target=
=3D"_blank" style=3D"color: #2DB9C5; text-decoration: none!important;">Atul=
 Ingle</a>
1 vote            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Last entry in newsletter has messed-up user links, gravatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306533/last-entry-in-newsletter-has-messed-up-user-links-gravatars)

Comment: Not that it matters a lot, but I feel this is not a duplicate (otherwise I wouldn't have written it) on the grounds that that one is "What's going on here?", not "This matters. Please change it."

Comment: How about plain text? :)