# Please make newsletters short enough that Gmail won't truncate them

Tags: feature-request, newsletter

I mistakenly subscribed to academia newsletters, I kept receiving emails without knowing how to unsubscribe because there's no link for that in the bottom. Today I noticed that if I click view entire message, only then I can unsubscribe.

The newsletter is too big to fit in an email and an unsubscribe link must be added from within the email.

Well at least I, because I can't for a small link in an email, press control + F and search for it, in SE newsletter, I cannot do that, unless I click view full message.

I'm using gmail, on a 22 inch screen, firefox latest version, also gmail android, also gmail chrome. If gmail shouldn't be supported by default, I don't know what is.

Comment: There *is* an unsubscribe link at the bottom of the email. Your email client is just cutting off the bottom of the email until you request the full version of it.

Comment: Doesn't that a requirement of the GDPR btw? to have everything clear to the user? I'm not from EU, I don't really know

Comment: @animuson it's gmail on firefox latest version and I have 22 inch screen. How big would my screen need to be? Shouldn't gmail be supported by default

Comment: It's your email provider doing the cut-off, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Nij you should fix the newseletter to support gmail and please read my comment above

Comment: If you receive a bill in the mail, and you proceed to grab a pair of scissors and cut it in half before opening it, you can't then complain that you didn't know you had an amount due because it was on the cut off part. Nobody but you is responsible for the mutilation of your messages. If you don't like Gmail doing that, then complain to Gmail.

Comment: @animuson why not make the newsletter a bit shorter or the font a bit smaller? why not complain to SE

Comment: I think you've missed the entire point. **Gmail** is making the cut-off. It's not something Stack Exchange can even fix!

Comment: @Nij I think SE could make the newseletter a bit smaller or the font a bit smaller or remove the slug

Comment: @Lynob It's not the font-size. Gmail cuts off after a certain number of bytes. We'd have to remove actual content to make it short enough to fit into said number of bytes. But the *whole point* of a newsletter is to see content.

Comment: @animuson you could remove an entire section called Greatest hits from previous weeks. it's a weekly newsletter and this is inside https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91872/how-do-i-handle-a-colleagues-gender-change-when-citing-their-paper a question from 10 month ago. Many questions could be removed

Comment: @animuson one could blame gmail and well never solve the problem, or you could blame the UX team and start designing a great newsletter that fits any client. Your choice

Comment: You're being very closed-minded here. You signed up for something that is meant to be a long list of content, and are then complaining that some email clients might chop it down because most emails aren't that long? You received what you signed up for. It has nothing to do with UX - it has everything to do with an email that is *intentionally long* not working with your *chosen client*. Both of those decisions rest solely on you. You haven't convinced anyone here that the problem is with us.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306533/last-entry-in-newsletter-has-messed-up-user-links-gravatars

Comment: Gmail is pretty ubiquitous, so while it's Gmail's problem not SE's, SE might consider working around it.  The problem isn't so much the content as the crazy-long URLs for every link in the message, so maybe it's possible to do something about that?

Comment: I have old newsletters in my inbox from 2016. They look great. The most recent SO newsletter can't even show all the "top new".
This is something SE can fix because their old content DID work.

Answer (score 7):

The email contains the link, as you said yourself. It's part of the email message already.

It's not really SE fault that some email clients truncate emails and show you only partial version.

I don't think SE should bend and change their logic just so it will fit certain email client.

Anyway, you can see all newsletters with links to subscribe/unsubscribe [here](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters).

Comment: "bend and change their logic just so it will fit certain email client" that way lies madness.

Comment: @MikeTheLiar I'm using gmail, GMAIL on a 22 inch screen. if gmail isn't one of the most popular email clients that must be supported by default, i dont know what is

Comment: @Lynob I take it you've never had to write or test HTML emails.

Comment: @Lynob Your screen size has nothing to do with where the email is cut off...

Comment: @Lynob so what if it's popular? It doesn't mean it's good.

Comment: @ShadowWizard as I said above, I think SE could make the newseletter a bit smaller or the font a bit smaller or remove the slug

Comment: please read my last 2 comments above sir. I'm tired of copy/pasting

Comment: @Lynob Font size also isn't relevant. It's all matter of bytes/characters. SE developer said something about long links that can become shorter, hopefully it will be done at some point.

Answer (score 0):

For historical reference.
Viewing a 2016 and a 2020 news letter in 2020 in android gmail.

2016:
[image: 2016]

2020:
[image: 2020]

2020 View entire:
[image: 2020 view entire]

All the new questions can't even be viewed in the 2020 version.

While this is a gmail anti-feature, It is reasonable for SE to work around it, as evidence old content still looks fine.

I basically will always hit delete before I hit show more.