# Reduce the size of site newsletters to ensure that they don't get clipped in Gmail

Tags: support, bug, design, email, newsletter

This is related to [a different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306533/last-entry-in-newsletter-has-messed-up-user-links-gravatars/306782#306782), but I'm going to propose specific changes.

The goal is to reduce the size of the message below 102K so Gmail stops truncate the message, hiding a portion of it behind a "view entire message" link.

First, remove the "preview" of the question. The only place on the sites where a preview exists is on the Questions view, and the truncated view doesn't offer me much of an insight that the question title and tags don't already offer. I don't have numbers in front of me, but I usually browse the site from the homepage view, which doesn't have previews, and I suspect that most people also use a similar view except when searching. If the emphasis is on a good question title and tags, I think that will also drive good user behavior to ensure that their questions are good, in addition to reducing the noise in an email newsletter.

Second, remove the "answered by", vote counts, and "asked by" (if it's allowed based on the removal of the question body preview and attribution rules). It's nice on the site, but I don't need this information in the email news letter. The addition of the names and gravatars only reduces the amount of content before a message gets truncated and doesn't help me decide if I want to click on a question or not.

Third, reorder the questions. Put the new questions at the top, questions I may be able to answer next, and then reviews of past weeks top questions at the bottom. This should help ensure that I see useful content, even if the message gets truncated.

Comment: "Asked by" / "answered by" may be necessary to comply with the attribution requirement, as the newsletter is redistributing the content created by those users.

Comment: @Mrs.Robinson Perhaps the asked by is. The answered by definitely is not, as no parts of answers are reproduced. The votes are also not required. I would question as if simply reproducing the title in the form of a link is sufficient to require attribution, though. Removing the gravatar would be a good step, if the name is still required.

Comment: I don't mind including the name of the asker, and a lightweight link (not the one with all the email bloat) to the profile might be necessary, but we don't need gravatars or links to answerers.